# Monotouch UITableViewCell DetailView

Tags: ios, uitableview, xamarin.ios

How can I implement an UITableViewCell with the chosen option on the right side.

It should look like this at the end:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

[MonoTouch.Dialog](https://github.com/migueldeicaza/MonoTouch.Dialog) has built it support for this using the RadioElement control.

You can also look at Apple's docs on building [UITableViewCells](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TableView_iPhone/TableViewCells/TableViewCells.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007451-CH7).